# how to prevent css div popup from jumping back to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm by no means well versed in JS, but I'm trying to put together a simple portfolio site for school with a black transparent div to act as a lightbox. I'm using CSS and JS to toggle this div, but on a long scrolling page, it jumps to the top when turned on. Here's my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
div.transbox{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0px 0px;
  position:fixed;
  background-color:#000000;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  z-index:99;
}
p.ptransbox{
    width:400px;
    padding:5px;
    position:relative;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    color:#000;
    border-radius:5px;
}
img.itransbox{
    padding:10px;
    position:relative;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

Here is the JS:

```
  var toggle2 = function() {
  var mydiv = document.getElementById('02');
  if (mydiv.style.display === 'none' || mydiv.style.display === '')
    mydiv.style.display = 'block';
  else
    mydiv.style.display = 'none'
  }
```

This is the code that is immediately viewable as the link to open the div (toggle on):

```
<td style="float:left; width: 33%" class="school">
<a title="Girl in Chair, 2012" class="tooltip" href="#" onclick="toggle2();" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image2','','images/thumbs/chairO.png',1)">
<img src="images/thumbs/chair.png" id="Image2" /></a>
```

And this is the code that brings the "lightbox" up, with the option to toggle it off:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle2();">
<div align="center" id="02" class="transbox" style="display: none;">
<p><img class="itransbox" src="images/anti-thumbs/chair.jpg" /></p>
<p class="ptransbox"><strong>Wörner Hall</strong>, 2010</p></div></a>
```

Please disregard all the Titles, Alts, or anything that is just specific to the content. You can see my portfolio in action here: http://www.student.nvcc.edu/home/majeffers3/ and if you notice, when you scroll to the bottom and click on an item, it jumps you to the top. I've been a long time lurker, first time I've ever posted a question because I can't seem to find the solution. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault()` in you click handlers for the anchor elements with `href="#"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action from taking place when the link is clicked. The simplest way to do this is to return `false` from the `onclick` handler:

```
<a title="Girl in Chair, 2012" class="tooltip" href="#" onclick="toggle2(); return false;" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image2','','images/thumbs/chairO.png',1)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change from `href="#"` to `href="javascript:;"`. It simply go to "#" link when you click.

Comment: Please do not use the javascript pseudo protocol, it is an artifact of an earlier time and is discouraged. "the javascript: pseudo protocol is discouraged over other alternatives, such as unobtrusive event handlers." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void You should be using Dark Falcon's method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you return false from your onclick handlers. If you don't, the default action for hyperlinks kicks in, which means you'll navigate to #, which means the top of the current page.